# Any way to force classes to have public static final field in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Is there a way to force classes in Java to have public static final field (through interface or abstract class)? Or at least just a public field?

I need to make sure somehow that a group of classes have

`public static final String TYPE = "...";`

in them.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are doing something that use reflection, right? Otherwise you wouldn't have the problem (if the field is referenced with `MyClass.field` but doesn't exists it won't compile so it's enforced implicitly, or the field is not referenced in which case you don't care)

Comment: You might want to consider a factory or similar.

Comment: @Tom Why bother with a mapping Class -> TYPE ? Just use the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: public fields are bad... if someone depends on them, and one day you change the field, the client code breaks

Comment: @Helper Client code only copies the values if `static final` fields are initialised with a *compile time constant* (as defined by the JLS - essentially primitive and Strings, literals, operators, no methods calls, no nulls).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can only force them to have a non-static getter method, which would return the appropriate value for each subclass:

```
public abstract String getType();
```

If you need to map each subclass of something to a value, without the need to instantiate it, you can create a `public static Map<Class<?>, String> types;` somewhere, populate it statically with all the classes and their types, and obtain the type by calling `TypesHolder.types.get(SomeClass.class)`

Answer (score 6):

You can define an interface like this:

```
interface X {
   public static final String TYPE = "...";
}
```

and you can make classes implement that interface which will then have that field with **the same value declared in the interface**. Note that this practice is called the [*Constant interface anti-pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface).

If you want classes to have **different values** then you can define a function in the interface like this:

```
interface X {
   public String getType();
}
```

and implementing classes will have to implement the function which can return different values as needed.

Note: This works similarly with abstract classes as well.

Comment: +1: I was about to downvote another answer because I didn't realize the OP wanted to have only the identifier, not the value, be the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have the compiler enforce this but I would look into creating a custom [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) rule which could check for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. But you could make an interface with a getType method

Answer (score 0):

Implement an interface in your classes and call a method from that interface, like [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464104/any-way-to-force-classes-to-have-public-static-final-field-in-java/2464123#2464123) have suggested.

If you must absolutely have a static field, you could make an unit-test that will go through the classes and checks with [Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) that every class has that public static final field. Fail the build if that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Or at least just a public field?

That's IMO the usual way to go: In the superclass, require a value in the constructor:

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {

  private final String type;

  protected MyAbstract(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }
}
```

This way, all implementations must call that super-constructor - and they don't have to implement getType() each.

Comment: But you can't call getType() statically.

Comment: No, you can't. But that was the second part of his question: "...to have public static final field... Or at least just a public field?" So I understand the question as: I'd like to do it statically, but if that's not possible, then at least non-statically.