# How does Android's Parcelable interface force implementing classes to have a static field?

Tags: java, android, oop

Android has an interface, Parcelable, which somehow forces implementing classes to have a `public static CREATOR` field.

From the documentation of the interface:

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a
>   non-null static field called `CREATOR` of a type that
>   implements the `Parcelable.Creator` interface.

There are two parts to my question:

1) How does this interface force implementing classes to have this static CREATOR field? How can I do this in my own Java interfaces? I cannot see how this works from Parcelable's source code.

For example:
If I had an interface Car, and I wanted each implementing class to have a public static String MANUFACTURER. Can this be done in a similar manner to Parcelable's `CREATOR` field?
I can of course add a `getManufacturer()` method to the interface, but I'm curious as to how the Parcelable forces the static field.

2) Following on from 1, how does Android access this field?
With an interface method you could do something like:

```
public void printManufacturer(Car car) {
    System.out.println(car.getManufacturer());
}
```

How would this work with a field?

I've tried researching how this works, but the only answers I've found are that [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464104/any-way-to-force-classes-to-have-public-static-final-field-in-java), however it's somehow being done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interface doesn't enforce having the field on the language level because it's impossible. If you don't "implement" that field error comes from Android lint instead.

If you're curious here's the source code of the check: [`ParcelDetector`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/ParcelDetector.java).

Then it uses reflection to access the static field since it knows both class name and field name.